# Canvasのimageの非表示方法

Tags: unity3d

UIのimageを非表示にする際、下のコードを使用しています。

```cs
GameObject.Find("Image").GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Image>().enabled = false;
```

この非表示方法だと他のスクリプトで表示にしたい際、UIのimageが取得できていないようなのですが、他のスクリプトでUIの取得方法もしくは他の非表示方法がないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

私も以前悩んでいたことがあり、下記を参考にして解決できました。
ページの真ん中辺りで該当の項目が出てきます。

> Buttonの表示・非表示を切り替える
>   http://qiita.com/2dgames_jp/items/b3d7d204895d67742d0c

gameObject.SetActive(false);は
GameObject.Find("Image").GetComponent().enabled = false;
にしても大丈夫だと思います。